# Execute PHP Within a Wordpress Theme File

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a calculator within a wordpress theme I have made, the code looks like this;

```
<?php //Template Name: Quote ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <article>
                    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <div class="post">
                        <form method="post" action="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/quote.php">

                            Counter 1: <input type="text" name="counter1width"> x <input type="text" name="counter1depth"><br>

                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate Now">
                        </form>

                        <?php
                            if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                                $counter1width = $_POST["counter1width"];
                                $counter1depth = $_POST["counter1depth"];

                                echo $counter1width*$counter1depth;
                            }

                        ?>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This is the error message I get...

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in
>   /home/landford/public_html/wp-content/themes/landfordstone/quote.php
>   on line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can no call the qoute.php file directly.

> 1) create new page template and in that page template write your code.
>
> 2) Create new Page and select the page template from dropdown.
>
> 3) Add that page url in form action.